# Searching in react-native-table-component

Tags: react-native, react-apollo

when entering a text in the search bar it should search within the table data to display the rows hat are matching with the search key and i am not able to find the exact required component in **react-native**.
can any one help me with this issue?
here is the code:

```
export default function ExampleOne() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USER_DETAILS);
    const head = ["id", "Name", "email"];
    if (loading) return <Text>Loading</Text>;
    if (error) return <Text>{`Error! ${error.message}`}</Text>;
    console.log(data.getUsers);
    const tableData = data.Users.map(rowObj => {
    delete rowObj["__typename"];
    return Object.values(rowObj);
    });
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#c8e1ff" }}>
        <Row
          data={head}
          style={styles.head}
          flexArr={[3, 2, 2]}
          textStyle={styles.text}
        />

        <Rows data={tableData} flexArr={[3, 2, 2]} textStyle={styles.text} />
      </Table>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SearchBar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html) from [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) . **onChangeText** of search bar update table view data

**Complete Code Sample**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search:"", 
    tableData: tableData: [
        ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['1', '2', '3', '3'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      ],
  };

  updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
    // update tableview data
  };

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;

    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
        value={search}
      />
    );
  }
```